# Sampling frequency vs Signal frequency

Tags: signal-analysis, sampling, frequency, nyquist, butterworth

I've started recently working with the ADXL345 accelerometer with the goal of finding the velocity.

And so far, I'm getting "okay" results after applying a second-order Butterworth filter to the acceleration values.

[image]
If you see in the picture below taken from the [ADXL345 datasheet](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ADXL345.pdf) p14, we can see that for example, to get 50Hz of useful signal frequency, 100Hz of sampling frequency needs to be used, which I guess follows the Nyquist-Shannon theorem.

I've configured my code to take measurements from the accelerometer every 100Hz which means the period should be 10 ms, but when I plot the signal and apply a Butterworth signal with a cutoff frequency of 50Hz I get the same signal, which is good because I wanted that 50Hz signal, but I don't know how it works, how come I took measurements every 100Hz and still got a signal of 50Hz?
Any help at this point would be greatly apperciated.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for my bad English, but I will try to explain it. Shannon-Nyquist theorem states that signal has to be sampled at least twice the maximal frequency. If you sample your signal with frequency of 100Hz, as i like to think of it, you will get 50Hz of spectral component on each side of spectrum(because it is symmetrical, you have both the negative and positive frequencies). So I think of it this way: you have 100Hz of spectral content, but on both sides of y axis(witch represents amplitude), we have 50Hz of content. So our maximal signal frequency after sampling with frequency of 100Hz will be 50Hz.[image: Here you can see how spectrum is symmetric]